# Discrete sets inside compact sets

Tags: general-topology

If $K$ is an infinite, compact, Hausdorff topological space, must $K$ contain a discrete, closed, countably infinite set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though the set cannot be closed. If $K$ has an infinite set of isolated points, a countable infinite subset of them does the trick. Otherwise we may assume without loss of generality that $K$ has no isolated points. Let $x_0$ and $x_1$ be distinct points; then have disjoint open nbhds $U_1$ and $V_1$, respectively. $V_1$ is infinite, so there is an $x_2\in V_1\setminus\{x_1\}$; let $U_2$ and $V_2$ be disjoint open nbhds of $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively, such that $U_2\cup V_2\subseteq V_1$. Keep going: given $x_n\in V_n$, let $x_{n+1}\in V_n\setminus\{x_n\}$, and let $U_{n+1}$ and $V_{n+1}$ be disjoint open nbhds of $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$, respectively, such that $U_{n+1}\cup V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n$.

In this way we recursively construct the countably infinite set $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and it’s not hard to check that this set is discrete.