# Using Urysohn's inductively

Tags: general-topology

Given an infinite, compact, Hausdorff topological space $K$, and a sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct points in $K$, I am trying to see if it is possible to use Urysohn's lemma to find a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ on $K$ such that $f_n(x_m)=\delta_{nm}$ with mutually disjoint supports.

that such a thing is possible, but I do not see how Urysohn's lemma gives the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the result in that answer you need only the weaker result that there is such a sequence in $K$. If $K$ has an infinite set of isolated points, let $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countably infinite subset of them, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ take $f_n$ to be the function that is $1$ at $x_n$ and $0$ everywhere else. Otherwise, carry out the construction in my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510190/discrete-sets-inside-compact-sets). For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an open $W_n$ in $X$ such that $x_n\in W_n\subseteq\operatorname{cl}W_n\subseteq U_n$. Now let $f_n$ be a Uryson function separating $x_n$ and $X\setminus W_n$: $f_n(x_n)=1$, and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\in X\setminus W_n$.

It isn’t necessarily possible to construct such functions for an arbitrary countably infinite set $S=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For example, we might have $D=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ and $X=[0,1]$.

Comment: Suppose $K$ is discrete and infinite. Your construction in such a case does not give me that $f_n$ are each continuous!

Comment: @Johnny: $K$ can’t be discrete and infinite, since it’s compact. Moreover, if it’s discrete, *every* function with domain $K$ is continuous.

Comment: Of course. (It's been a long time since I've taken/used basic topology. Excuse my ignorance!)

Comment: @Johnny: Not to worry; it happens!

Comment: Could you perhaps explain to me, where, in answer number 3, in the link I provided, Nate uses the reflexivity condition?

Comment: @Johnny: Not without spending a *lot* of time refreshing my knowledge of functional analysis: it’s been a couple of decades since I used it. You could leave a question there for Nate: he’s still active.